# Encode an ADT / sealed trait hierarchy into Spark DataSet column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

If I want to store an Algebraic Data Type (ADT) (ie a Scala sealed trait hierarchy) within a Spark [DataSet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) column, what is the best encoding strategy?

For example, if I have an ADT where the leaf types store different kinds of data:

```
sealed trait Occupation
case object SoftwareEngineer extends Occupation
case class Wizard(level: Int) extends Occupation
case class Other(description: String) extends Occupation
```

Whats the best way to construct a:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataSet[Occupation]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** There is no good solution right now, and given Spark SQL / `Dataset` implementation, it is unlikely there will be one in the foreseeable future.

You can use generic `kryo` or `java` encoder

```
val occupation: Seq[Occupation] = Seq(SoftwareEngineer, Wizard(1), Other("foo"))
spark.createDataset(occupation)(org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Occupation])
```

but is hardly useful in practice.

UDT API provides another possible approach as for now (Spark `1.6`, `2.0`, `2.1-SNAPSHOT`) it is private and requires quite a lot boilerplate code (you can check `o.a.s.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` to see example implementation).

Comment: why is kryo hardly useful in practice? Is it because we have to specify kryo serializer after every transformation?

Answer (score 2):

I have once dived deeply into the subject and created a repo showcasing all the approaches I have found could be useful.

Link: https://github.com/atais/spark-enum

Generally, [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082540/1549135) is right, but you might find it useful to understand the full picture.