# Generic class to read csv in scala

Tags: scala, csv, generics, case-class

I am new to Scala and I am trying to build a framework that can read multiple types of csv files and all read operations will go through one class. For eg, I have two types of CSVs: `Student` and `Professor` and I am doing something like this.

```
abstract class Person
case class Student(name: String, major: String, marks: Double) extends Person
case class Professor(name: String, salary: Double) extends Person
```

my csv reader looks something like this

```
  private def readCsv[T: Encoder](location: String) = {
    spark
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .csv(location)
      .as[T]
  }

def data:Dataset[Person](location) = readCsv[Person](location)
```

I am getting a compile-time error in the last line as `No implicit arguments of Type: Encoder[Person]`. Call to this method looks something like this:

```
val studentData = storage.data[Student]("Student.csv")
```

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to supply an implicit argument. You can do this in three ways: (1) by defining an `implicit val` in scope, or (2) by defining an `implicit class`, or (3) by explicitly passing the mising `Encoder` argument in a secondary argument list.

Comment: When you're getting an error, it's helpful if you include the error and any associated stack traces in the question. For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am getting a compile time error `No implicit arguments of Type: Encoder[Person]` at line `def data:Dataset[Person](location) = readCsv[Person](location)`

Comment: Seems related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082540/864369 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454596/864369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. your ADT definition should probably be final/sealed else it's hard to derive `Encoders` for it.
2. IIRC Spark does not support Sum types sadly because there is no schema representation for it. A somewhat common hack is to represent `Either[A, B]` as `(Option[A], Option[B])` but yeah it's a pain