# Add ADT column in Spark dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, algebraic-data-types, apache-spark-encoders

I want to create a dataset which contains an ADT column. Based on this question: [Encode an ADT / sealed trait hierarchy into Spark DataSet column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030073/encode-an-adt-sealed-trait-hierarchy-into-spark-dataset-column)
I know, that there's a solution which encodes with kryo, but that is not really helpful.
Theres's another way to solve the issue which is far better. Let's define the following ADT:

```scala
sealed case class Animal(sound: String)
object Cat extends Animal("miau")
object Dog extends Animal("wuff")
```

and define a case class which uses `Animal`

```scala
case class Pet(name: String, sound: Animal)
```

I can easily create now a dataset from Pet

```scala
val ds = List(Pet("Tom", Cat), Pet("Beethoven", Dog)).toDS
ds.show()
+---------+------+
|     name| sound|
+---------+------+
|      Tom|[miau]|
|Beethoven|[wuff]|
+---------+------+
```

Note, that *sound* is a `Struct`, but to extract the element is straightforward:

```scala
ds.select("name", "sound.*").show()
+---------+-----+
|name     |sound|
+---------+-----+
|Tom      |miau |
|Beethoven|wuff |
+---------+-----+
```

Actually this is the final structure that I want to achieve.
There are two problems that I am facing.

1. Usually it's not a good idea to inherit from a case class
2. Exhaustive pattern matching ask for default case

Example for problem 2:

```scala
 def getSound(animal: Animal): String = animal match {
   case Cat => Cat.sound
   case Dog => Dog.sound
   case _ => ""
 }
```

To overcome problem 2, I though of creating a *sealed abstract class*. I also want to maki it a product

```scala
sealed abstract class Animal(sound: String) extends Product
case object Cat extends Animal("miau")
case object Dog extends Animal("wuff")
```

Now problem 2 is handled, and no more default case required. However I am not able to create a dataset from Animal. I get the following exception:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find sound on class Animal`

What I really want to obtain, is to get the same behaviour as the `Option`.
We can create an a case class which contains an optional field:

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Int])
List(Person("Jack", Some(26)), Person("Julia", None)).toDS.show()
+-----+----+
| name| age|
+-----+----+
| Jack|  26|
|Julia|null|
+-----+----+
```

I checked the implementation of *Option* and it's a sealed abstract class too, so what I am missing?
How is the Option encoded for datasets?

**UPDATE**

Sorry the last part with *Option* doesn't make too much sense here, since there you need to write explicitly the value which you want to see in the end in the dataset.

But the question remains, how could I encode a column created from an ADT with proper pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was an *apply* method for my *Animal* class.

```scala
sealed abstract class Animal(val sound: String) extends Product with Serializable
  case object Cat extends Animal(sound = "miau")
  case object Dog extends Animal(sound = "wuff")
  object Animal {
    def apply(animal: Animal): String = animal match {
      case Cat => Cat.sound
      case Dog => Dog.sound
    }
  }
```

Using this I can obtained the almost-desired result:

```scala
val ds = List(Pet("Tom", Cat), Pet("Beethoven", Dog)).toDS
ds.show()
+---------+------+
|     name| sound|
+---------+------+
|      Tom|[miau]|
|Beethoven|[wuff]|
+---------+------+
```

Comment: This will never work on cluster, because of abstract class. It will throw a RTE `org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 44, Column 11: Cannot instantiate abstract "Animal"`

Comment: Interesting, I was trying it out in spark shell (version 2.4.0-cdh6.3.1, client mode), and generated the dataset with the desired schema. I will try to run in cluster mode too, using a jar

Answer (score 0):

The [sanyi14ka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391689/1549135) will actually never work.

The topic of ADT/Enum Encoders in DataSet is not new, but even today it does not work properly.

You might find useful those two link:

- [Encode an ADT / sealed trait hierarchy into Spark DataSet column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41030073/1549135)
- My repo on this subject: https://github.com/atais/spark-enum